# Can I say "What opinion are you of?"

Tags: formality

We can say "I'm of the opinion that ~" instead of "I reckon that ~" in a formal way.

Then, can I say "What opinion are you of?" in place of "What do you reckon?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't imagine any native speaker saying that. It would be 'What's your opinion?'

Comment: Unless it was a native speaker two centuries ago...?

Comment: @Bidella: The closest the OED gets is with these two citations: ‘To fish out . . .what opinion the Emperor is of us’ (1531) and ‘What opinion my Lord Coke was of . . .is not so certain’ (1715). However, in other contexts, ‘opinion’ is frequently found without an article, as in ‘I am of opinion that . . .’